# how to make vuetify v-btn element a click event

Tags: javascript, jestjs, vuetify.js

I have this vuetify button

```
 <v-btn
  @click="resetQuiz"
 >
    Click to Start
 </v-btn>
```

I am testing for a click event on button click

```
  it(`should trigger an event when the 'click to start' button is clicked`, () => {
    const event = jest.fn()
    const button = wrapper.findComponent({ name: 'v-btn' })
    expect(button.exists()).toBe(true);

    expect(button.text()).toBe('Click to Start')
    console.log(button);
    
    button.vm.$emit('click')
    expect(event).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0)

    button.trigger('click')
    expect(event).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
  })
```

Apparently no event is emitted cause when I log button this is what I get.

```
VueWrapper {
      isFunctionalComponent: undefined,
      _emitted: [Object: null prototype] {},
      _emittedByOrder: [],
      selector: { name: 'v-btn' }
    }
```

This line of the test `expect(event).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)` fails.
I have tried `<v-btn @click="resetQuiz()">`,
`<v-btn @click.native="resetQuiz">`, and
`@click.native="resetQuiz()">`

This is my method

```
methods: {
    resetQuiz () {
      window.location.reload()
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide a working demo? The example you gave seems to be working just fine. I don't get the `it()` function at all.

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-container>App
        <v-btn @click="resetQuiz">
          Click to Start
        </v-btn>
      </v-container>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
<script>
  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    vuetify: new Vuetify(),
    methods: {
      resetQuiz() {
        console.log('RESET');
        //window.location.reload()
      }
    }
  })
</script>
```

Comment: The button works just fine on the app just as your demo is working and does exactly what I want. It just does not pass on the tests and I do not understand why. I am trying to test that the button clicks, that's what the `it()` function is supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

So, I found the fix after researching multiple resources.

First I was testing with `shallowMount` instead of `mount`. `mount` allows you to retrieve events automatically recorded by the wrapper unlike `shallowMount` which only renders some parts of the component.

```
const wrapper = mount(SomeComponent, {
    localVue,
    vuetify,
  })
```

Secondly, I encountered a jest problem with router-link. I imported router from my local router `@/router` then added router to my wrapper

```
const wrapper = mount(Welcome, {
    localVue,
    vuetify,
    router: router
  })
```

Thirdly jest dom threw a navigation error on the console cause I was using `window.location.reload()`. This is my method now

```
methods: {
    resetQuiz () {
      window.location.assign('/quiz')
    }
  }
```

Finally I had to assign my jest function to the window.location. This is what the complete test looks like. `delete window.location` deletes any existing location

```
describe('SomeComponent.vue', () => {
  const localVue = createLocalVue()
  let vuetify

  const { location } = window

  beforeAll(() => {
    // @ts-ignore
    delete window.location

    window.location = { ...window.location, assign: jest.fn() }
  })

  afterAll(() => {
    window.location = location
  })

  beforeEach(() => {
    vuetify = new Vuetify({})
  })

  const wrapper = mount(SomeComponent, {
    localVue,
    vuetify,
    router: router
  })

  it('should trigger when the start button is clicked', () => {
    const event = window.location.assign = jest.fn()

    const button = wrapper.findComponent({ name: 'v-btn' })
    expect(button.exists()).toBe(true)

    expect(button.text()).toBe('Click to Start')

    button.trigger('click')
    expect(event).toHaveBeenCalled()
    expect(event).toBeCalledWith('/quiz')
  })
})
```

You might encounter problem with typescript testing `window.location`, you need to add `node` to `tsConfig` `compilerOptions`

```
compilerOptions: {
...
"types": [
      ...
      "node"
],
}
```